# Replace string parts that appear twice Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, regexp-replace

I am trying to work out in Oracle how to isolate/highlight word combinations in a concatenated string like the one below:

```
Some words##Again words##More of this||@@@@||Some words##Again words##Other
```

The idea is to find the word combinations that appear **exactly twice** and replace them by 0 so I'm left with the ones that appear only once, either on the left side of the `||@@@@||` or on the right side. The result of the query should be something like this:

*Highlighted*

```
Some words##Again words##More of this||@@@@||Some words##Again words##**Other**
```

*Replaced*

```
0##0##More of this||@@@@||0##0##Other
```

To give you some more information about the concatenation: the left side (before the `||@@@@||`) is my current customer record, while on the right hand side I have the previous version. By making the replacements I can reveal any differences between customer records.

I have tried to get this done by using:

- **regexp_replace**: this does not work entirely with `REGEXP_REPLACE(MY STRING,'((Some words){1,2})|((Again words){1,2})','0',1,0)` as for some reason the string parts in my first record are never correctly replaced. I'm also hitting the limits of this function due to the number of word combinations I need to match;
- **nested CASE WHEN**: does not work either obviously as CASE WHEN - even nested - stops when the first match is found but I need to have all conditions checked and replaced.
- I have thought about using subselects, but as this query uses one of the largest tables in my schema, this will not be usable except on a per customer basis. And it might still not work...

Some more information in order to find a solid, performant solution:

- I have 34 possible word combinations to match
- I have no idea which ones will be there, ever, except when I run the query obviously
- I have no idea in which order they will be in the concatenated string

I hope this is clear. Anyone with some magical ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to replace one duplicated term at each iteration:

```sql
WITH replaced ( value, start_char ) AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           '(##|^)([^#]+?)((##[^#]+?)*\|\|@@@@\|\|([^#]+?##)*)\2(##|$)',
           '\10\30\6',
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(
           value,
           '(##|^)([^#]+?)((##[^#]+?)*\|\|@@@@\|\|([^#]+?##)*)\2(##|$)',
           1
         )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           '(##|^)([^#]+?)((##[^#]+?)*\|\|@@@@\|\|([^#]+?##)*)\2(##|$)',
           '\10\30\6',
           start_char + 1
         ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(
           value,
           '(##|^)([^#]+?)((##[^#]+?)*\|\|@@@@\|\|([^#]+?##)*)\2(##|$)',
           start_char + 1
         )
  FROM   replaced
  WHERE  start_char > 0
)
SELECT value
FROM   replaced
WHERE  start_char = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'Some words##Again words##More of this||@@@@||Some words##Again words##Other' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '333##123##789##555||@@@@||123##456##789##222##333' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE                                 |
> | :------------------------------------ |
> | 0##0##More of this||@@@@||0##0##Other |
> | 0##0##0##555||@@@@||0##456##0##222##0 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=01955a309147cb90a630a7201fe62265)*

## Explanation:

The regular expression matches:

- `(##|^)` either two `#` characters or the start of the string `^` (in the first capturing group `()`);
- `([^#]+?)` one-or-more characters that are not `#` (in the second capturning group `()`);
- `(` the start of the 3rd capturing group;

  - `(##[^#]+?)*` two `#` characters followed by one-or-more non-`#` characters (in the 4th capturing group `()`) all repeated zero-or-more `*` times;
  - `\|\|@@@@\|\|` then two `|` characters, four `@` characters and two `|` characters;
  - `([^#]+?##)*` then one-of-more non-`#` characters followed by two `#` characters (in the 5th capturing group `()`);
- `)` the end of the 3rd capturing group;
- `\2` a duplicate of the 2nd capturing group; then
- `(##|$)` either two `#` characters or the end-of-the-string `$` (in the 6th capturing group).

This is replaced by:

- `\10\30\6` which is the contents of the 1st capturing group then a zero (replacing the 2nd capturing group) then the contents of the 3rd capturing group then a second zero (replacing the matched duplicate) then the contents of the 6th capturing group.

The query will replace a pair of duplicate terms in the string (if they exist) and `REGEXP_INSTR` will find the start of the match and put the values into `value` and `start_char` (respectively); then at the next iteration the regular expression will start looking from the next character on from the start of the previous match, so that it will gradually move across the string finding matches until no more duplicate terms can be found and `REGEXP_REPLACE` will not perform a replacement and `REGEXP_INSTR` will return `0` and the iteration will terminate.

The final query filters to return the only the final level of the iteration (when all the duplicates have been replaced).

Comment: Thanks for this! It works when I put this in my source query. Can you briefly explain what the  regular expression and the replace are actually doing? I'm totally new to regex so curious to find out more. Also, the 'prev_value' serves what purpose exactly?

Comment: @Postino Updated with an explanation. `prev_value` was something I was using in an earlier version of the query when I was trying to do it without `REGEXP_INSTR` but that method didn't work and it is now irrelevant to the query but I had forgotten to remove it; it's removed now.

Comment: Grand! Will need to find out more detailed information about regular expressions. They are very handy in some cases.

Comment: Would this work on any string containing the same separators but of variable length and with potentially other characters in it like commas?